# (sql) how can I use count() method when data type is text?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select count(category) from list where category like 'action'
```

above is a query i want to run. However, when I run that query, I am getting 
data type error. 
is there any alternative method for `count()`? or... how can I use `count()` method 
when data type is text?

Comment: what is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: What type is `category`? I bet it isn't a string.

Comment: Just a tip, don't use `like` when you aren't using the special characters (`%`) allowed for `LIKE`. It'd be easier to do this: `WHERE category = 'action'`

Comment: This query should work if category is a varchar/nvarchar field? Are you sure it is the correct data type?

Comment: You can't - so just don't count `TEXT` columns - or better yet: stop using `TEXT` as datatype, it's deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 anyway - use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead (which **CAN** be counted again). Also: are your `category` column **REALLY** in need of 2 GB of text??? Wouldn't `VARCHAR(100)` be **more than sufficient** for a `Category` ??

Comment: @Amaan - The reason the OP needs to do that is because they are inapropriately using the `text` datatype and `=` is not allowed on text.

Comment: @MartinSmith Really? Never knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant apply COUNT() function on text,ntext,image datatypes.

Why you can't use :

```
select count(*) from list where category like 'action'
```

? Do you have some nulls ?

If you don't have to exclude null value the above query could already work well ...

Comment: I am getting data type error... Can you count on a text field ? How ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title for future googlers you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE
               WHEN some_text_column IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             END)
FROM   some_table
```

In your case though (as pointed out in the comments by [@hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd)) the `WHERE  category LIKE 'action'` predicate ensures that any `NULL` values will be excluded anyway so it is safe to replace it with `COUNT(*)`

Moreover you almost certainly should not be using the `text` datatype for this. This is a deprecated datatype that was intended for holding LOB (Large Object) data over 8000 bytes.

Strings like "action" definitely do not fit this description!

Comment: This is a bad example though: if `category LIKE 'action'`, then `category IS NOT NULL`, so it's not so much that the intended behaviour was that of `COUNT(*)`, it's that `COUNT(category)` (if it were valid) and `COUNT(*)` have the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

`count()` always return `int` like type.

Read result data with `int` accessor: eg. `getInt(1)`