# Why can't you use COUNT() method on text?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Although workarounds to this problem have been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634508/sql-how-can-i-use-count-method-when-data-type-is-text%20here) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979413/the-text-ntext-and-image-data-types-cannot-be-compared-or-sorted-except-whe), why you actually can't use COUNT() on text data type? Is it a technical limitation? Does anyone knows what internal mechanism drives this?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? As a non MS SQL Server user I can't see why? The aggregate function COUNT should work on all data types. If the column value is not null it's counted, if it is null it's not counted.

Comment: There's a lot of things you cannot do on text which you can do on for example varchars. That's also why the datatypes are deprecated. You should do what is suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name if having to use text. The specific implementation limitation however I do not know.

Comment: Yes, exactly as jarlh mentioned, we know the solution. But still, why it's not possible to count on any data type?

Comment: Don't know the reason. Presume it is something historic. Even without casting it is trivial to work around with `COUNT(CASE WHEN YourTextCol IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)` though so doubt it is any technical limitation. Probably just something that was never implemented and never will be as they are deprecated.

Comment: One internal mechanism that differs is that the internal storage of text is always "out of row". The replacement `nvarchar(max)` can store a portion of the data (8000 bytes) "in row" and does not have to do any LOB reads to figure out if the value is null or not. Is that the reason? No I don't think so. The reason is probably because the data type is deprecated and no more development has been put into it since there was a replacement added back in SQL Server 2000 or something like that.

Comment: And why are you still using a deprecated datatype? Unless your database is SQL Server 2000 or lower, you need to change text fields to varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your actual question:

The old large-format/LOB datatypes: TEXT, NTEXT and IMAGE, are archaic/obsolete datatypes that had numerous technical limitations (for instance you could not use UPDATE on one directly).

Microsoft fixed this in the SQL Server 2005 release, but in order to preserve compatibility with prior versions, did so with three *new* datatypes: VARCHAR(MAX), NVARCHAR(MAX) and VARBINARY(MAX).  You should switch to using these datatypes instead, which are better in almost every way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've already figured out a solution, but for others searching for the answer, this will work. The case statement returns a 1 for each row where a non-Null or empty string is found, a 0 for each row that's empty or Null. It works for character and numeric fields. The Sum() function outside effectively returns the count:

```
select sum(
     case when YourField >'' then 1
     else 0
     end
) 'mycount'
from YourTable
```