# How to count distinct results from a already executed SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, distinct

```
    select application from l3_usage 
where function in ('dbms', 'web', 'app') 
group by application, function 
order by application
```

[image]

This is the result image when I execute the above query.

I want to now count the number of times applications occur. So for example:
Budget : 3
CSR : 3
FMS : 3
Facilities : 1
Inventory : 3

etc...

I have tried

```
   select application, count(application) from l3_usage 
where function in ('dbms', 'web', 'app') 
group by application 
order by application
```

but I get random count numbers that do not relate to the count I was looking for.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT :::::

my ultimate purpose of doing this is to get only applications that have count values less than 3.

Which in this case, should return just "Facilities" and "SCM".

Comment: Replace count(application) with count(*)

Comment: @kojow7 This does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT x.application, COUNT(*) As Frequency
FROM
(
    SELECT application
    FROM l3_usage
    WHERE function IN ('dbms', 'web', 'app') 
    GROUP BY application, function 
    ORDER BY application
) AS x
GROUP BY x.application
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

I query the result set you posted in your answer and obtain the `COUNT` for each group.  Notice that this `COUNT` is the number of unique `function` values for each `application` group.  You should get this result:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| application | Frequency |
+-------------+-----------+
| Facilities  |     1     |
| SCM         |     1     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

**Update:**

A much easier way to do your query is:

```
SELECT application, COUNT(DISTINCT function) As Frequency
FROM l3_usage
WHERE function IN ('dbms', 'web', 'app') 
GROUP BY application
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT function) < 3
ORDER BY application
```

You had the right idea in the beginning, but you needed to `SELECT` the number of distinct `function`s for each application group.

Comment: http://puu.sh/gLUBF/58d321f459.png This is what i get, which is also what we dont want

Comment: @BryanLee Can you have another look at my updated query.  It should work this time ^ ^.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT application,COUNT(CASE
               WHEN application IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             END)
FROM   table group by application
```

I found reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8635631/2630817)

### Edit

---

```
select * from(
SELECT typing,COUNT(CASE
               WHEN typing IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             END) as counts
FROM   ss  group by typing ) abc where counts<3
```

Comment: @BryanLee it should can you tell me what exactly you are doing?

Comment: my ultimate purpose of doing this is to get only applications that have count values less than 3.

Which in this case, should return just "Facilities" and "SCM".

Answer (score 0):

I have used subqueries which I had concatenated count to your query. If you want distinct row count use `distinct` in-front of `count(*)` in **@count** query

```
declare @count nvarchar(max)= (select count(*) 
                               from l3_usage 
                               where function in ('dbms', 'web', 'app'))

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select a,count(*),'+@count+' as count  from l3_usage 
where function in (''dbms'', ''web'', ''app'') '

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: This line is not getting executed in to oracle. Hmm syntax error perhaps? Also I have yet to learn "declare" and "exec" phrases :/